# R change data.frame structure from pairwise columns to pairwise rows

Tags: r, dataframe

Change this:

```
From        To
A           D
B           E
C           F
```

to:

```
From        To
A           B
B           C
D           E
E           F
```

My data contains several hundred lines and not 3 as in the example.

**Note**: To clarify the names in the initial `data.frame` are two separate paths that I want to format into an edge list. I do not want to connect the two paths.

In this case we want to void the edge between C and D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Data

```
df <- data.frame(From=LETTERS[1:3], To=LETTERS[4:6], stringsAsFactors=F)
```

#### Solution splitting paths

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(From = head(unlist(df),-1), To = head(lead(unlist(df)),-1)) %>%
           filter(row_number() != nrow(df))
```

#### Explanation

`unlist` linearizes your `df` by column. `lead` moves entries up a position.

#### Output

```
  From To
1    A  B
2    B  C
3    D  E
4    E  F
```

Comment: This will allow for the connection from C to D though.

Comment: Added a `filter` statement to do this

Comment: why use `toupper(letters[1:3])` yet there is `LETTERS[1:3]`? curious though.

Comment: Because I didn't know `LETTERS` was a different thing. Updated my data. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try this using `zoo` ?

```
A=c(Data$From,Data$To)
B=as.data.frame(zoo::rollapply(A,2,paste))


  V1 V2
1  A  B
2  B  C
3  C  D
4  D  E
5  E  F
B[!B$V1%in%Data$From[length(Data$From)],]

  V1 V2
1  A  B
2  B  C
4  D  E
5  E  F
```

PS . change the name by using `names(df)=c('Form','To')`

Comment: Is there a way to cut out the C and D connection?

Answer (score 2):

All in ***`Base R`***:

```
#[-nrow(dat), ] This removes the link between to columns (i.e. From C To D row)
data.frame(From = unlist(dat)[-length(unlist(dat))], To = unlist(dat)[-1], 
    row.names = NULL)[-nrow(dat), ] 

##   From To
## 1    A  B
## 2    B  C
## 4    D  E
## 5    E  F
```

***Data:***

```
 dat <- structure(list(From = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"      
     ), class = "factor"), To = structure(1:3, .Label = c("D", "E",        
     "F"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("From", "To"), row.names = c(NA, 
     3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Is there a way to exclude the C and D connection? The columns in the initial data.frame actually correspond to different paths.

Comment: in your code just use `row.names = NULL` instead of using a `sequence`

Comment: @Onyambu you're right but I am trying to find a way to address the another issue with row names.

Comment: Variation on a theme - `ud <- unlist(dat); data.frame(from=head(ud,-1), to=tail(ud,-1))[-nrow(dat),]`